# How to display an empty textbox if the value equals zero?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple view in which I use an HTML Helper to generate a text input :

```
@Html.TextBox("Something",Model.myObject.myValue)
```

myValue is a float.

If `myValue==0`, I don't want to display `0`. Is it possible, and how ?

Thanks !

Comment: If `0` represents the absense of a value, you could consider using a nullable `int?` instead.

Comment: No, the value is initialized with 0, but I don't want to have "0" in the text input when the form is displayed as a blank form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use a simple inline conditional when setting the value:

```
@Html.TextBox("Something", Model.myObject.myValue == 0 ? "" : Model.myObject.myValue.ToString())
```

Conversely, it might be cleaner to do this in the model itself.  You can add a calculated property to the model definition:

```
public string MyNonZeroValue
{
    get { return myObject.myValue == 0 ? "" : myObject.myValue.ToString(); }
}
```

Then just bind to that model property:

```
@Html.TextBox("Something", Model.MyNonZeroValue)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about just adding a quick check?

```
@Html.TextBox("Something", Model.myObject.myValue == 0 ? string.Empty : Model.myObject.myValue.ToString())
```

Comment: This solution works, if I add "ToString()" at the end, like David suggested below.

Comment: @Matt Yep, mixing my types in ternary operator... __updated__